# Screen recording ios audio zoom

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ipados

I have been trying to screen record zoom several zoom meetings on my iPad in the last few weeks but I am unable to figure out why there is no audio. I have tried the same on my iPhone and I never had this no audio issue.

Comment: However, you are aware that you cannot make a screen recording when the microphone is used by the application.

Answer (score -1):

Kindly note that during screen recording, the audio coming out of the speakers of iPad & iPhone is recorded along with any other external noise. There is no internal redirection of audio, so you need to allow the zoom audio to play through inbuilt speakers and should avoid using earphones for it to be recorded.